# Emacs lisp: Translate characters to standard ASCII transcription

Tags: emacs, unicode, character, elisp, translation

I am trying to write a function, that translates a string containing unicode characters into some default ASCII transcription. Ideally I'd like e.g. `Ångström` to become `Angstroem` or, if that is not possible, `Angstrom`. Likewise `α=χ` should become `a=x` (c?) or similar.

Does Emacs have such *built-in* capabilities? I know I can get the names and similar of characters (`get-char-code-property`) but I know no built-in transcription table.

The purpose is to translate titles of entries into meaningfully readable filenames, avoiding problems with software that doesn't understand unicode.

My current strategy is to build a translation-table by hand, but this approach is fairly limited and requires a lot of maintenance.

Comment: This code from Xah Lee is a partial solution to your question: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_zap_gremlins.html

Comment: Thanks, that helps. At least it allows to create a standard translation table for some common characters (even if not optimal, e.g. the German ü is usually transcriped into ue).

Comment: There is no global "optimal". The character `ü` is used in other languages which do not transliterate it to `ue`.

Comment: Do they use the same unicode character also?

Comment: Yes. Some languages consider it a letter in its own right and some treat it as a modified letter, but all use the same code point. It is in general true that there are different ASCII-transliteration conventions for different languages/cultures which disagree for many code points.

Comment: Okay, this means then that what I wanted to do is basically impossible (at least for a hobby project). I guess I'll just opt for calculating entry names from file names instead (and allowing only a safe subset for the file names) so as to force a bijective relation artificially.

Comment: you could try to look into input methods since they basically do the same thing, only the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in capability that i know of. I wrote a package [`unidecode`](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/unidecode) specifically for your task. It uses the same approach as in [Python's same-named](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) library. To install just add MELPA repository to your repository list:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
  '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
```

Then run <kbd>M-x package-install RET unidecode</kbd>. `unidecode` has 2 functions, `unidecode-unidecode` that turns Unicode into ASCII, and `unidecode-sanitize` that discards non-alphanumeric characters and transforms space into hyphen.

```
ELISP> (unidecode-unidecode "¡Hola!, Grüß Gott, Hyvää päivää, Tere õhtust, Bonġu Cześć!, Dobrý den, Здравствуйте!, Γειά σας, გამარჯობა")
"!Hola!, Gruss Gott, Hyvaa paivaa, Tere ohtust, Bongu Czesc!, Dobry den, Zdravstvuite!, Geia sas, lmsllmlllmckhmslmgll"
ELISP> (unidecode-sanitize "¡Hola!, Grüß Gott, Hyvää päivää, Tere õhtust, Bonġu Cześć!, Dobrý den, Здравствуйте!, Γειά σας, გამარჯობა")
"hola-gruss-gott-hyvaa-paivaa-tere-ohtust-bongu-czesc-dobry-den-zdravstvuite-geia-sas-lmsllmlllmckhmslmgll"
```